# Is there a comprehensive list of problems in OR?

Tags: optimization, modeling

I was trying to search for different types of problems in OR and couldn't find a exhaustive list of problems.  So far I have,

1. Travelling salesman problem
2. Cutting Stock problem
3. Shortest path problem
4. Knapsack problem
5. Coloring problem
6. News vendor problem
7. Assignment problem
8. Scheduling problem
9. Facility location problem
10. Demand supply / Production planning problem
11. Diet problem

I am obviously forgetting a lot of them. Can you add and extend the list?

Comment: These are all optimization problems, and your question has the optimization tag. If you only want optimization problems, you might consider changing "OR" (which encompasses many other things) to "optimization" in the title.

Comment: Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/865/what-are-common-and-not-so-common-abbreviations-in-operations-research

Comment: Most (all?) OR problems boil down to: Figure out how something does or could work, and make it work better.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: No. There are so many variants of e.g. the vehicle routing problem, that a comprehensive list of only those problems, would be even very long. Or, of course, it depends on what you consider *comprehensive*. An exhaustive list is at least not feasible to make.

Answer (score 1):

12. Loss function optimization (basis of ML)
13. Reinforcement learning / Dynamic programming
14. Policy/Value optimization
15. Vehicle routing problem & it's variants (Chinese postman etc.)
16. Stochastic & Robust optimization

Answer (score 0):

17. Timetabling optimization problem
18. Transportation/Transbording problem